# Finding string elements of an array in another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two sorted arrays `h` and `M`:

```
h = np.array(['blue', 'red', 'white'])
M = np.array(['blue', 'green', 'orange', 'red', 'white'])
```

and would like to find the indices at which each element of `h` appears in `M`

Can I `np.where` for this?

Also, it can be the case that an element of `h` might not appear in `M` and in this case, I don't require the index for it. The elements do not repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is another way and is a one-liner that will return an `ndarray` of the indices of the matches.

```
np.nonzero(np.in1d(M, h))[0]
```

Output

```
array([0, 3, 4])
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple for loop should do:

```
for value in h: 
    print(np.where(M==value))
```

Or

```
print(np.where([M==value for value in h]))
```

Comment: thank you - is it possible to convert this in one line where it will store the indices? 
also, there is the second piece that i edited above just now

Answer (score 0):

Here is how:

```
import numpy as np

h = np.array(['blue', 'red', 'white'])
M = np.array(['blue', 'green', 'orange', 'red', 'white'])

i = np.where([h == i for i in M])
print(i[0])
```

Output:

```
[0 3 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the indices I would use Python's built-in [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function. Like this:

```
indices = []
for ind, val in enumerate(M):
    if val in h:
        indices.append(ind)
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking advantage of `M` and `h` being sorted:

```
h = np.array(['blue', 'red', 'white'])
M = np.array(['blue', 'green', 'orange', 'red', 'white'])

# find indices
idx = M.searchsorted(h)
# avoid index error if last entry of h is larger than last of M
idx = idx[:idx.searchsorted(len(M))]
# filter out unmatched elements
idx[M[idx]==h]
# array([0, 3, 4])
```